# How to match drawableleft borders with its parent edittext's borders?

Tags: android

I am trying to add a drawableleft to an Edittext:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editUserName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_email"
    android:hint="@string/login_identity_hint"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

As you see, the image does not match its parent's borders, there is padding from left, bottom and top even though i do not set any padding. What can i do about it?

I also tried the following approach:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/editUserNameContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_email"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
                android:id="@+id/editUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:hint="hint"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

But this time, it looks like the following: The image and edittext's heights do not match and there is a small gap between them:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking the only way you can get it to be how you want is to do something like this....

Remove **android:drawablePadding="5dp"** from EditText

Remove **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"** from EditText

Add **android:paddingLeft="50dp"** to EditText

Add **android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"** to ImageView

This will just put the image over the top of your edit text, and using the padding to move the text in the edit text box to the right a bit after the image. You may need to make adjustments to the image view to make it fit just right

Let me know how this works!

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_email"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/editUserName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:hint="hint"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```